# Android Dagger2 Building a module like this

Tags: android, dependency-injection, dagger-2

I have a module

```
@Module
public class UtilModule
{
    private Context context;

    private Fragment fragment;

    public UtilModule(Context context)
    {
        this.context = context;
    }

    public UtilModule(Fragment fragment)
    {
        this.fragment = fragment;
    }

    @Provides
    @Named("fragmentUtilActivity")
    public FragmentUtils providesFragmentUtilForActivity(Context context)
    {
        return new FragmentUtils(context);
    }

    @Provides
    @Named("fragmentUtilFragment")
    FragmentUtils providesFragmentUtilForFragment(Fragment fragment)
    {
        return new FragmentUtils(fragment);
    }

    @Provides
    Context provideContext()
    {
        return context;
    }

    @Provides
    Fragment provideFragment()
    {
        return fragment;
    }

}
```

This is FragmentUtil class

```
public class FragmentUtils
{
    private Context context;

    private Fragment hostFragment;

    public FragmentUtils(Context context)
    {
        this.context = context;
    }

    public FragmentUtils(Fragment hostFragment)
    {
        this.hostFragment = hostFragment;
    }

    public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, boolean addToBackStack)
    {
        FragmentTransaction transaction = ((Activity) context).getFragmentManager()
                                                              .beginTransaction();
        transaction.add(R.id.fragment_container, fragment, null);

        if(addToBackStack)
        {
            transaction.addToBackStack(null);
        }

        transaction.commit();
    }

    public void addNestedFragment(Fragment fragment, boolean addToBackStack)
    {
        FragmentTransaction transaction = hostFragment.getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        transaction.add(R.id.nested_fragment_container, fragment, null);

        if(addToBackStack)
        {
            transaction.addToBackStack(null);
        }

        transaction.commit();
    }

    public void replaceNestedFragment(Fragment fragment, boolean addToBackStack)
    {
        FragmentTransaction transaction = hostFragment.getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        transaction.replace(R.id.nested_fragment_container, fragment, null);

        if(addToBackStack)
        {
            transaction.addToBackStack(null);
        }

        transaction.commit();
    }
}
```

And here is the component

```
@Component(modules = {UtilModule.class, FragmentModule.class})
public interface ApplicationComponent
{
    void inject(PickerDashboardActivity target);

    void inject(PickerDashboardFragment target);

    void inject(PickingFragment pickingFragment);
}
```

Now what i want is to have both variants of FragmentUtils in my Activity i.e via providesFragmentUtilForActivity and providesFragmentUtilForFragment in UtilModule class.

Is it possible to achieve this like

```
@Inject
    @Named("fragmentUtilActivity")
    FragmentUtils fragmentUtilsActivity;

@Inject
    @Named("fragmentUtilFragment")
    FragmentUtils fragmentUtilsFragment;

    ApplicationComponent component = DaggerApplicationComponent.builder()
                                      .utilModule(new UtilModule(context))
                                      .utilModule(new UtilModule(fragment))
                                      .build();
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using two constructor , you can use single constructor in your UtilModule , like this

```
@Module
public class UtilModule
{
private Context context;

private Fragment fragment;

public UtilModule(Context context,Fragment fragment)
{
    this.context = context;
    this.fragment = fragment;
}

}
```

And in your activity, do this

```
ApplicationComponent component = DaggerApplicationComponent.builder()
                              .utilModule(newUtilModule(context,fragment))
                                  .build();
```

after that, inject your activity

```
  component.inject(this)
```

Otherwise rest of your code is correct

Comment: that would kill the purpose of making two constructors. Also when from activity i might not have the fragment and it would be unnecessary to pass both if i only need the utility for activity or fragment,

Comment: you are correct, then I think in that case you should make a separate module and component for your fragment and invoke that component and pass your module.The objects which are required in fragment class should be requested in fragment class

Comment: Yes that's an approach which will work but i think this will create a lot of overhead and class to manage and will add bioler plate rather than reducing. Let's wait and see what are the thoughts of other users. Thanks for the answer :)

Comment: In your scenario, you are creating a fragment in your activity and passing it to your module, so now your fragment is available in your dagger graph and it is not going to die till your activity is alive

Comment: I think this is not correct way, you should not pass fragment in your module where you are providing objects related to your activity

Comment: because fragments have there own lifecycle and modules providing dependency related to fragments should have there own dagger graph

Comment: In your first comment you have mentioned " Also when from activity i might not have the fragment ..." so this scenario is not going to arrive.